# Error al conseguir el contenido de una URL

Tags: android-studio

Aqui esta el error:

```
2019-01-19 21:25:53.801 25369-25369/RubenPX.ROX E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: RubenPX.ROX, PID: 25369
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1450)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:102)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:90)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:787)
    at com.android.okhttp.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:175)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:141)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:83)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:174)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:407)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:538)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source:0)
    at RubenPX.ROX.WebAPI.WebApi.GetWebResponse(WebApi.java:21)
    at RubenPX.ROX.WebAPI.LogIn.LogIn(LogIn.java:9)
    at RubenPX.ROX.Main$LogIn.onClick(Main.java:31)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6520)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:440)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Aqui esta el codigo:

```
public static String GetWebResponse(final String url) {
    try {
        // Create URL
        URL githubEndpoint = new URL("https://api.github.com/");

        // Create connection
        HttpsURLConnection myConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) githubEndpoint.openConnection();

        myConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "my-rest-app-v0.1");

        if (myConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            InputStream responseBody = myConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader responseBodyReader = new InputStreamReader(responseBody, "UTF-8");


            return responseBodyReader.toString();
        } else {
            return "Error: " + myConnection.getResponseCode();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Llamada

```
String Res = WebApi.GetWebResponse("http://www.google.com");
```

Lo que estoy intentando hacer, es conseguir el contenido de una URL, pero no me deja.

Comment: hay una parte del error que dice Cauded By pero no la has puesto

Comment: En que linea dices? no lo encuentro

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de encontrar la respuesta sin querer: aqui la teneis.

[How do I fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9289190/10532835)